# Spark Cluster mode issue to read Hive-Hbase table on Kerberized Environment

Tags: apache-spark, hive, hbase, kerberos, cluster-mode

## Error description

We are not able execute our Spark job in yarn-cluster or yarn-client mode, though it is working fine in the local mode.

This issue occurs when we try to read the Hive-HBase tables in a Kerberized cluster.

## What we have tried so far

1. Passing all the HBASE jar in the –jar parameter in spark submi

`--jars /usr/hdp/current/hive-client/lib/hive-hbase-handler-1.2.1000.2.5.3.16-1.jar,/usr/hdp/current/spark-client/lib/datanucleus-api-jdo-3.2.6.jar,/usr/hdp/current/spark-client/lib/datanucleus-rdbms-3.2.9.jar,/usr/hdp/current/spark-client/lib/datanucleus-core-3.2.10.jar,/usr/hdp/current/hbase-client/lib/hbase-client.jar,/usr/hdp/current/hbase-client/lib/hbase-common.jar,/usr/hdp/current/hbase-client/lib/hbase-protocol.jar,/usr/hdp/current/hbase-client/lib/htrace-core-3.1.0-incubating.jar,/usr/hdp/current/hbase-client/lib/protobuf-java-2.5.0.jar,/usr/hdp/current/hbase-client/lib/guava-12.0.1.jar,/usr/hdp/current/hbase-client/lib/hbase-server.jar`

2. Passing Hbase site and hive site in file parameter in Spark submit

`--files /usr/hdp/2.5.3.16-1/hbase/conf/hbase-site.xml,/usr/hdp/current/spark-client/conf/hive-site.xml,/home/pasusr/pasusr.keytab`

3. Doing Kerberos authentication inside the application.  In the code we are explicitly passing the key tab

   UserGroupInformation.setConfiguration(configuration)
   val ugi: UserGroupInformation = 
   UserGroupInformation.loginUserFromKeytabAndReturnUGI(principle, keyTab)
   UserGroupInformation.setLoginUser(ugi)
     ConnectionFactory.createConnection(configuration)
   return ugi.doAs(new PrivilegedExceptionActionConnection {
     @throws[IOException]
     def run: Connection = {
   ConnectionFactory.createConnection(configuration)    }
   })
4. Passing key tab information in the Spark submit
5. Passing the HBASE jar in the spark.driver.extraClassPath and spark.executor.extraClassPath

## Error Log

```
18/03/20 15:33:24 WARN TableInputFormatBase: You are using an HTable instance that relies on an HBase-managed Connection. This is usually due to directly creating an HTable, which is deprecated. Instead, you should create a Connection object and then request a Table instance from it. If you don't need the Table instance for your own use, you should instead use the TableInputFormatBase.initalizeTable method directly.
18/03/20 15:47:38 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 0.0 in stage 7.0 (TID 406, hadoopnode.server.name): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Error while configuring input job properties
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.hbase.HBaseStorageHandler.configureTableJobProperties(HBaseStorageHandler.java:444)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.hbase.HBaseStorageHandler.configureInputJobProperties(HBaseStorageHandler.java:342)
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.RetriesExhaustedException: Failed after attempts=50, exceptions:
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: SASL authentication failed. The most likely cause is missing or invalid credentials. Consider 'kinit'.
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcClientImpl$Connection$1.run(RpcClientImpl.java:679)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
Caused by: GSSException: No valid credentials provided (Mechanism level: Failed to find any Kerberos tgt)
```

Comment: My 2 cents : `yarn-cluster` is very tricky with Hive/Kerberos _or_ with HBase/Kerberos; mixing both is... ambitious. Focus on `yarn-client` first.

Comment: The Spark launcher is supposed to create Kerberos **tokens** for Hive, HBase, etc then push these to the executors. Either the HBase token is skipped (no log unless you are in DEBUG level in log4j) or the Hive-HBase interface does not support tokens, only old-fashioned UGI credentials.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve this by adding following configuration in the ***spark-env.sh***

> export SPARK_CLASSPATH=/usr/hdp/current/hbase-client/lib/hbase-common.jar:/usr/hdp/current/hbase-client/lib/hbase-client.jar:/usr/hdp/current/hbase-client/lib/hbase-server.jar:/usr/hdp/current/hbase-client/lib/hbase-protocol.jar:/usr/hdp/current/hbase-client/lib/guava-12.0.1.jar

And removing the *spark.driver.extraClassPath* and *spark.executor.extraClassPath* in which I was passing the above Jar from the Spark submit command.